# Get child element and set it position: fixed

Tags: lightning-web-components

Still pretty new to LWC and trying to understand the communication between parent/child and how to create logic to it.

So, the goal here is to have the child component with position: fixed when you start scrolling the page until it reaches a certain point, where it is set to position: relative

I've set a class to the child component and I'm calling it within the parent, but I'm seeing a "SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }"

This is due to the Locker service and here's my doubt...the logic should be done in a window scroll event, how to select the child component by class and change it's position?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="col">    
    <c-detail-gallery
       class="product-gallery">
    </c-detail-gallery>
</div>
```

The JS to select it:

```
stickyProductGallery() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let productGallery = this.template.querySelector('.product-gallery');
        console.log('product gallery element' + productGallery);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like your parent LWC needs to control something in your child LWC.

As per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_data_flow), to pass data down to the child you need to expose a property on the child and pass the data down.

e.g.

in you child detailGallery.js component, you could have:

```
@api position;

get propertyClass() {
    return `${this.position === 'relative' ? 'slds-is-relative' : 'slds-is-absolute'}`;
}
```

and in your detailGallery.html, you could have:

```
<div class={propertyClass}>
    your content goes here
</div>
```

i.e. Given your parent LWC has the knowledge of when to be relative/absolute, it needs to tell your child LWC.  It can't reach into the child like you're trying to do, so the child needs to expose a parameter that understands what to do with this information and how it will make itself relative/absolute